# Debugging React Native App on Android Device. No 'Debug JS Remotely' option

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have my React Native application running on my Android Device with USB debugging, after running `adb  -d reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and `react-native run-android` in my project.

In the Chrome developer tools, my device is listed in `remote devices`.

According to many blogs and the docs themselves (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html), I should be able to select 'Debug JS Remotely' in my device's Developer Options, but I have no such option.

Navigating to http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui renders the following message:

```
React Native JS code runs inside this Chrome tab.

Press ⌘⌥J to open Developer Tools. Enable Pause On Caught Exceptions 
for a better debugging experience.

Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.
```

Reloading on my device does not do anything.

I am using a OnePlus 3 device on Android 7.1.1 (although this problem also occurs when running an Android Lollipop emulator)

Please advise how to debug my react native project in chrome tools.

Thanks

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: Did you reach the developer options (shake the device)?

Comment: I have reached the developer options menu, and I am using a OnePlus 3

Comment: Just click right button on your chrome browser and select inspect. The debugger usage is same to use like you use inspect web developer console on chrome. For quick test in your RN app just type console.log('Hello World') and see it print out in your browser console

Comment: Thank you, but I have nothing to right click on except the 'Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.' message

Comment: Oh, I finally meet someone experiencing the same issue like me.. But I am still struggling on it...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet to this ? I am facing this problem now...

Answer (score -1):

Try this method.

Go to `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` in your project, and just keep the following code.

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Your projec name</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

In `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`, comment out following line.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
     <!-- <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> -->
     ...
</style>
```

In `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`, comment out following lines.

```
<resources>
     <string name="app_name">xxxxx</string>
     ...
     <!-- <string name="catalyst_debugjs"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_element_inspector"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_jsload_error"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_jsload_message"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_jsload_title"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_reloadjs"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_settings"></string>
     <string name="catalyst_settings_title"></string> -->
     ...
</resources>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `Genymotion` to debug react-native app

Comment: Genymotion android emulator does not have 'Debug JS remotely' option, either